# Laravel pagination with search parameters

Tags: php, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I've having trouble preserving my search parameters when clicking on a pagination link.  For example, if a search query returns 40 records and I have two pages, clicking on the second page will return the second page of the full set of records instead of just the 40 that were returned by the search.

Here is the `postIndex()` from my controller:

```
public function postIndex(){

    $validator = Validator::make(
        Input::all(),
        array('priceMin' => array('numeric'),
            'priceMax' => array('numeric')
            )
    );

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('items')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('items')->withInput();
    }
}
```

And my `getIndex()`:

```
public function getIndex(){

    $items= $this->retriever->getListings(Input::old(), 20);

    return View::make('listings', array('items' => $items);
}
```

The `retriever` object then loops through the old input and finds all valid search parameters, queries the database with them, and paginates with the specified amount, 20 in this case.

I've tried to use `->appends()` but then the data isn't in `Input::old()` and it makes for a terrible url if there are 10 search parameters since it uses `GET` and not `POST`.  How can I get my parameters applied to the pagination links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would never ever use POST request to do any filtering/sorting/searching!!! This is just wrong

In general, if user tries to reload page (search result page) that some data (search params) has been sent to, browser asks whether it should reload and resend that data again. I must not say, this is annoying, at least.

Solution: stick with Laravel method and use `appends()` despite the fact it generates 'ugly' URL - this is a common solution, regardless the framework.

Comment: You can also save the search-params to your database and only use the search-id and page in the url. More work but clean :)

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution as well. This way, you can discover what users search for, etc.

Comment: Yup, this is something I just recently did, as I was initially doing it like you. I'm not saving the search queries though. Will probably implement that soon.

Comment: @RobGordijn Could you expand on your idea?  I was planning to save searches down the road anyway.  I'm not sure how to redirect from `postIndex()` with the search id in the URL

Comment: @vikingsfan19 The basic idea is to let the user fill in the searchform and let it post to your app. In the post-method you must get, validate and save the entered search parameters. Create a `Search` model with information from your `User`. Have a `SearchRules` with a relation to `Search` so you can save every search parameters (id, search_id, name, value). After saving redirect the browser to a page like /search/result/1337. 1337 will be the id of `Search`. Fetch the rules for that search, fire your searchclass and display the results. In that way the url is clean(er) and you got search stats

Comment: How would you be able to use the `pagination` class with that method?  The `->appends()` method will make use of `GET` rather than another route.

Comment: Why not just save the search params in a session variable? Saving the search params in a database is overkill.

Comment: Why do you think so? User details for logged in user are retrieved on every page load and no one dies. Searching does not happens so often compared to this. Storing search queries might help you to improve you services - you just know what users are looking for on your site/ecommerce... If you do not need this, just drop this idea :)